# JTextArea is not automatically scrolled on printing in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextarea

My problem is that the `JTextArea` with `JScrollPane` added is not scrolling to the newest line printed (the scroll bar stays at the top).
The caveat is that lines are printed in the separate `SwingWorker` thread.

Whereas, if I get rid of `SwingWorker` in the `simulation()`, the scrolling seems to be working fine.

Can someone please give me a hint how to cope with this?

Here is the code I am testing on (`import`s omitted):

```
public class Test4 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JButton btnNewButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test4 window = new Test4();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test4() throws InterruptedException {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnNewButton = new JButton("Test Scrolling");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                simulation();
            }
        });

    }

    private void simulation() {
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                TestOutputStream customOutputStream = new TestOutputStream(
                        textArea);
                System.setOut(new PrintStream(customOutputStream, true, "UTF-8"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    System.out.println("TEST");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        swingWorker.execute();
    }
}

class TestOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final JTextArea consoleOutput;

    public TestOutputStream(JTextArea consoleOutput) {
        super();
        this.consoleOutput = consoleOutput;
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        consoleOutput.append(buf.toString("UTF-8"));
        buf.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        buf.write(b);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is the code I am testing on (imports omitted):

Why? Post code that we can copy/paste/test. I don't use an IDE and should not have to spend the time to enter the imports.

Your code didn't do anything when I tested it. I'm using JDK8 on Windows 7.

I had to add the following after your loop in the SwingWorker:

```
customOutputStream.flush();
```

> is not scrolling to the newest line printed (the scroll bar stays at the top).

It doesn't scroll because the text is not appended to the text area on the EDT.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

The above code worked for me.

Check out [Text Area Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for more information on this problem.

Comment: Just edited the code, modified:
`System.setOut(new PrintStream(customOutputStream, true, "UTF-8"));`
Thanks for the answer, checking it.

Comment: `DefaultCaret` worked for me either. Thanks so much!